# How to fix the ratingControl class in iOS Xcode app Food Tracker?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

[ratingControl class error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZK2f.png)

How do I fix the errors that happen with this line of code? I've tried everything. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you use?

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan 7.2 I'm pretty sure

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses Swift 2.2 syntax, which is available from Xcode 7.3.

See Xcode 7.3 release notes for more details https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

`The Objective-C selector of a Swift method can be determined directly with the #selector expression, for example:
let sel = #selector(insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)) // sel has type Selector`

So the answer to your question - you need to update your Xcode from 7.2 to 7.3 version, and the error will go away.

If you don't want to update Xcode - use an old `selector` syntax, for example:

```
selector: "ratingButtonTapped"
```

Comment: Thank you for the example.  Unfortunately I am trying to update Xcode 7.3 in the app store and it isn't working. When I try to do the old syntax, the same error still occurs.